# sprite nodes on touch first one only takes physics body

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8.1 `Swift` 3 to make small bouncing game.

The player is supposed to create walls around a bouncing ball and this ball is supposed to bounce on each wall.

On touch down, I move to point and on touch ended, I create a line share node between the two touches began and end.

I added the physics that were needed to my node, then I added child to this node (see my node below).

What happens is that for each touches began and touches ends, 'Swift' draws the line node and attaches it to self but only the first node bounces the ball.
All lines (walls) after the first one is not affecting the ball.

Here is my code the GameScene Swift file:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
// vars lets and nodes
let startingBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
let myPath = CGMutablePath()
let ballCategory : UInt32 = 1
let wallCategory : UInt32 = 2

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        myPath.move(to: t.location(in: self))
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        myPath.addLine(to: t.location(in: self))
        let wallNode = SKShapeNode(path: myPath)
        wallNode.lineWidth = 5.0
        wallNode.fillColor = SKColor.green
        wallNode.strokeColor = SKColor.green
        wallNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: myPath)
        wallNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
        self.addChild(wallNode)
    }
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    startingBall.fillColor = SKColor.red
    startingBall.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2)
    startingBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    startingBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    startingBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    startingBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    startingBall.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    startingBall.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    startingBall.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.0
    self.addChild(startingBall)

    startingBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 3.0, dy: 3.0))
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all i've fixed it

actually mutable path myPath defines line between touch begin and touch end lines to draw shape node only ... while physics edge created for each touch series from node to node ...

in steps
1- i added start point and end point variables
2- pick up start node in touch begin and end node in touch end
3- i set physical body for from point to point start node and end node

1-

```
var startPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
var endPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
```

2- ..

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:   UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        startPoint = t.location(in: self)
        myPath.move(to: t.location(in: self))
    }
}

        endPoint = t.location(in: self)
```

3- ..

```
        wallNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFrom: startPoint, to:  endPoint)
```

for help you can set show physics to true in skiver

```
    skview.showsPhysics = true
```

thanks